# ORA-00904 invalid identifier even the column exists

Tags: sql, oracle, select, identifier

I have query in which i want to result the SUBSCRIPTION_ID,ORDER_NUMBER.The query is working fine.But i also want to show now the START_DATE when the SUBSCRIPTION_ID are created. But i am getting an errors after this as :

```
ORA-00904: "WF"."START_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Here is my query:

```
    select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,iw.ORDER_NUMBER,WF.START_DATE
    from (
       SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
       '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>',''),'</ax2130:id>','')) 
       AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
       CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML,'<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'),'<ns7:orderType>',''),'</ns7:orderType>','')
      AS VARCHAR(100)) AS    order_type,TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML,'<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber>'),'<ax2147:orderNumber>',''),'</ax2147:orderNumber>','')) 
      AS ORDER_NUMBER,
       CREATE_DATE
       FROM
       SOAP_MONITORING,WF_WORKFLOW ww
       where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
    ) iw
    where iw.order_type='NEW' and iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IN
    (select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
       from WF_WORKFLOW WF where WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID' 
    and WF.STATUS_ID=0 and WF.START_DATE < sysdate - 30 / (24 * 60))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `WF_WORKFLOW` only is available in the scope of the subquery used for the `IN` predicate and you're referencing it outside that scope.

I think you could rewrite the query to use a join instead like this:

```
select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,iw.ORDER_NUMBER,WF.START_DATE
from (
       SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
       '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>',''),'</ax2130:id>','')) 
       AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
       CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML,'<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'),'<ns7:orderType>',''),'</ns7:orderType>','')
      AS VARCHAR(100)) AS    order_type,TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML,'<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber>'),'<ax2147:orderNumber>',''),'</ax2147:orderNumber>','')) 
      AS ORDER_NUMBER,
       CREATE_DATE
       FROM
       SOAP_MONITORING,WF_WORKFLOW ww
       where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
    ) iw
inner join WF_WORKFLOW WF on iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
where iw.order_type='NEW' 
and WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0 and (WF.START_DATE < sysdate - 30 / (24 * 60))
```

Obviously I haven't tested it...

Comment: Hello the query runs but now the WF.START_DATE not showing the correct time from last 30 minute which i want. Its also showing the result from last month.

Comment: @Rahul It's unclear to me if you want records older than 30 minutes, or if you want records within the last 30 minutes. If it's the later maybe the condition at the end of the query should be `(WF.START_DATE >= sysdate - 30 / (24 * 60))`?

Comment: Ohh i am sorry it was correct. I want older than 30 minutes and its giving the correct results.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The table WF is not present in the FROM clause. You cannot SELECT on this table.

May be you want something like this :

```
FROM (...) iw
INNER JOIN WF_WORKFLOW WF on WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID=iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
WHERE iw.order_type='NEW' AND WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID'
AND WF.STATUS_ID=0 and WF.START_DATE < sysdate - 30 / (24 * 60)
```